# query is not fetching the max record and not incrementing PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my query not fetching the max record and also it's not incrementing. 
can you  help me figure what is wrong with my code?

```
 private function basicInformation() {
    // initialize variables
    $host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "test";
    $tbl_name = "ballpark_details";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    // connect to database
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); # ORDER BY ballpark_details_id DESC
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(ballpark_details_booking_ref) FROM `ballpark_details`");
    //Getting the max ref_id
    $values = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);    
    $html = "";
    $html .= '<fieldset id="basic-information" class="ui-widget">' . PHP_EOL;
    $html .= '<legend>Basic Ballpark Information</legend>' . PHP_EOL;
    $rowClass = "input-row";
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputBookingRef($values['ballpark_details_booking_ref']), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputBank(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputRegion(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputDescription(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputNotes(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputStartDate(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputRequestedDeliveryDate(), $rowClass); #$this->inputEndDate()
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputExpiryDate(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputURL(), $rowClass);
    $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputCAR(), $rowClass);
    (strcmp($_GET["page"], "createballpark"))?
        $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputProjectStatusEdit(), $rowClass) :
        $html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputProjectStatusCreate(), $rowClass);         
    $html .= '</fieldset>';
    return $html;
}


private function inputBookingRef($value){ //($value) {
    //$value = $this->bookingRef;
    $html = "";
    //$value = 10307;
    $value++;
    $html .= '<label for="ref">Booking Ref: </label>';
    $html .= HTML::inputText("ref", 20, $value) . PHP_EOL;
    return $html;
}
```

In here, I want to increment the value in booking ref. textbox. But when I try to run the program, it's giving number 1 not the last max value.

Comment: I (we) strongly recommend using PDO for database queries (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). It's easy to learn and has massive benefits - security, for one.

Comment: I agree to previous comment.. but if you wann stick with mysql_query.. and if you are trying to get last inserted row in the table.. try using mysql_insert_id()..http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$values = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
```

`$values` does not contain the value of MAX.

So you will have to use.

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(ballpark_details_booking_ref) AS MAXValue FROM `ballpark_details`";

$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die ("The Following query is not properly executed: ".$query."<br>");

//Getting the max ref_id

while ($result !=-1 && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$max = $row['MAXValue'];
}
```

Then

```
$html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputBookingRef($max), $rowClass);
```

Comment: tried ur code but php threw at me Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean

Answer (score 0):

You must change `$values['ballpark_details_booking_ref']` to `$values['max(ballpark_details_booking_ref)']`.

You can also add an alias to your query and use that as an index into the result

```
SELECT MAX(ballpark_details_booking_ref) as max_booking_ref FROM `ballpark_details`
```

and then

```
$html .= $this->wrapLabelTextbox($this->inputBookingRef($values['max_booking_ref']), $rowClass);
```

Comment: Better would be to use an alias in the SQL.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche it's still giving me 1. I followed through ur code

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes Add an `echo print_r($values, true)` to see the contents of the returned result set.

Comment: hi I added print_r($values, true) but still in my textbox #1 is always showing not the next sequence.

Comment: Ok, and what is the content of `$values`?

Comment: You have a line `//$value = 10307;`. When you uncomment this line, do have the value `10308` in your textbox?